# Checking if null value is present in three columns and creating a new column in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

So currently, I have a Spark DataFrame with three column and I'm looking to add a fourth column called `target` based on whether three other columns contain null values. For example,

```
+-------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|column_1     |column_2   |column_3   |   target  |  
+-------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|          1  |       null|       null|    FAIL   |
|         null|       null|       null|    PASS   |
|         null|         1 |       null|    FAIL   |
|         null|       null|       null|    PASS   |
|         null|       null|       null|    PASS   |
|         null|       12  |       null|    FAIL   |
|         null|       null|       null|    PASS   |
|         null|       null|       null|    PASS   |
|         null|       null|         2 |    FAIL   |
```

If column_1, column_2, column_2 are all null I want the value in the target column to be pass, else FAIL. Initially, I thought a UDF or Pandas UDF would do the trick, but from what I understand you should use PySpark function before you use a UDF, because they can be computationally expensive.

Since I'm new to PySpark one of the methods I'm first trying out is `df.withColumn("target", col("column_1").isNull()).show(n=10)`. It kinda work. I'm just confused on what the best way to check all three at once and instead the `target` column being true or fail. I want to specify the value to be `PASS` or `FAIL`. Are there any other PySpark function or method I should be aware of to get the resulting `target` column I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `coalesce` for this. `coalesce` will return first non-null value from multiple columns. If all are nulls, it will return null.

```py
df = df.withColumn('target', F.when(F.coalesce('column1', 'column2', 'column3').isNull(), 'PASS').otherwise('FAIL'))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work when columns are of different types. Input to `coalesce` should all be the same type.

Answer (score 2):

You can utilise [Higher Order Functions](https://towardsdatascience.com/higher-order-functions-with-spark-3-1-7c6cf591beaa) for this -

#### Data Preparation

```
s = StringIO("""
column1|column2|column3
1|null|null
null|null|null
null|1|null
null|null|null
null|null|null
null|12|null
null|null|null
null|null|null
null|null|2
""".replace('null',''))

df = pd.read_csv(s,delimiter='|')

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(df)\
             .withColumn('column1',F.when(F.col('column1') == "NaN",F.lit(None)).otherwise(F.col('column1')))\
             .withColumn('column2',F.when(F.col('column2') == "NaN",F.lit(None)).otherwise(F.col('column2')))\
             .withColumn('column3',F.when(F.col('column3') == "NaN",F.lit(None)).otherwise(F.col('column3')))

sparkDF.show()

+-------+-------+-------+
|column1|column2|column3|
+-------+-------+-------+
|    1.0|   null|   null|
|   null|   null|   null|
|   null|    1.0|   null|
|   null|   null|   null|
|   null|   null|   null|
|   null|   12.0|   null|
|   null|   null|   null|
|   null|   null|   null|
|   null|   null|    2.0|
+-------+-------+-------+
```

#### ForAll

Transform a `combined` column as `ArrayType` as higher order functions require an array input

```
sparkDF = sparkDF.withColumn('combined'
                             ,F.array(*[F.col('column1'),F.col('column2'),F.col('column3')])
                            )


sparkDF = sparkDF.withColumn('target',F.forall('combined', lambda x: x.isNull()))\

sparkDF.show(truncate=False)

+-------+-------+-------+------------------+------+
|column1|column2|column3|combined          |target|
+-------+-------+-------+------------------+------+
|1.0    |null   |null   |[1.0, null, null] |false |
|null   |null   |null   |[null, null, null]|true  |
|null   |1.0    |null   |[null, 1.0, null] |false |
|null   |null   |null   |[null, null, null]|true  |
|null   |null   |null   |[null, null, null]|true  |
|null   |12.0   |null   |[null, 12.0, null]|false |
|null   |null   |null   |[null, null, null]|true  |
|null   |null   |null   |[null, null, null]|true  |
|null   |null   |2.0    |[null, null, 2.0] |false |
+-------+-------+-------+------------------+------+
```

Comment: Upvote for elegance and simplicity.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work when columns are of different types. Input to `array` should all be the same type

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic version of Emma's one which allows to check if record is all with null values.

```
data_columns = df.schema.fieldNames()

df = df.withColumn(
    "is_null_record",
    F.when(
        F.coalesce(*[F.col(x).cast(StringType()) for x in data_columns]).isNull(),
        True,
    ).otherwise(False),
)
```